# Regex match when is followed by a space or no space

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi how can I write regex for matching a word only when there's a space before the word or no space?

currenlty my regex is like this `/(R)(\ )([0-9]+)/gi` and it matches the word that is not followed by a space.

[image]

I want to match R 23, r30 if it is followed by a space or no space.

for example:

```
const str  = 'R 34 r 45, for 2 a day';
console.log(str.replace(/(R)(\ )([0-9]+)/gi,'R$3')) 
//prints "R34R45, foR2 a day"
//expected "R34 R45, for 2 a day"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need word boundary before R and no need for capture, can use lookahead instead.

Search: `\bR (?=\d)` and replace with `R`

Comment: Yes, and you also may replace the space with `\s+` to match any 1+ whitespace chars.

Comment: Your regex don't convert `r45` to `R45`. use this: `/\bR\ ?(?=\d)/gi`